# If I have an extra StarCraft II license, can I share it without violating the license terms?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

If I have a Battle.net account with a *StarCraft II* license that is extra (I don't play it), would it be in accordance with, or against the license terms if let my friends use it?  (Only one at any given time though.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65714/is-it-possible-to-run-more-than-one-battle-net-game-at-the-same-time-on-differen

Comment: @Anto That one deals with running the games at the same time, whereas this is to do with only one running at any given time.

Comment: Ok sorry, my bad ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because legal questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Voting to reopen as per the meta post: [Are questions about ToCs/EULAs allowed?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9857/4797)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, no. That would require that they log in under your Battle.net account, and that's against the [Terms of Use](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/about/termsofuse.html).

Emphasis mine:

> Username and Password
>
> During the Account creation process, you may be required to select a unique username and/or a password (collectively referred to hereunder as "Login Information"), and **you may not share the Account or the Login Information with anyone other than as expressly set forth herein.** You are responsible for maintaining the confidentiality of the Login Information, and you will be responsible for all uses of the Login Information, including purchases, whether or not authorized by you. In the event you become aware of or reasonably suspect any breach of security, including without limitation any loss, theft, or unauthorized disclosure of the Login Information, you must immediately notify Blizzard by emailing wowaccountadmin@blizzard.com.

It does appear, however, that you could transfer the license, although it is not guaranteed:

> Game Transfers.
>
> The Authentication Key that accompanies most Game clients can only be used once, and will connect a Game license to the Account under which it is registered. The transferability of your license to a Game client is governed by the Game EULA; provided, however, that any transfer of the Game client shall have no impact on the Account registered to you, and that Account shall not transfer with the Game client. **Purchasers of a license to a used Game client must follow the process detailed on the www.Blizzard.com website, which may require payment of a processing fee.**

More specifically, the [StarCraft 2 EULA](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/legal/sc2eula.html), mentions that transfers are generally prohibited. However, if you're in a jurisdiction where transfer is allowed, they do have a process for it:

> No Transfer or Sublicense.
>
> THE GAME IS LICENSED, NOT SOLD. NEITHER THE GAME NOR THE LICENSE GRANTED IN SECTION 1 MAY BE SUBLICENSED OR TRANSFERRED TO ANY OTHER PERSON OR ENTITY, AND ANY ATTEMPT TO DO SO SHALL BE NULL AND VOID. If a court of competent jurisdiction finds the foregoing sentence to be unenforceable, you agree that you will call Blizzard Customer Service at 1-800-592-5499 to arrange for the transfer of your rights under this Agreement to another person with a valid Battle.net account; provided, however, that Blizzard may charge a processing/handling fee to facilitate the transfer, issue a unique key to the transferee, and remove the preexisting key from the Battle.net account registered to you.

Comment: What is the point of allowing more than one StarCraft 2 License on a Battle.Net account then?

Comment: @Vaccano Off the top of my head, I can think of a few reasons: being able to play in multiple regions & pro gamers who want to practice on sock-puppet accounts so they're not harasses when they log in.

Comment: Isn't the account the Battle.net net account?  Or can each license on a single Battle.net account have a seperate "Log in"?

Comment: @Vaccano According to [this forum thread](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/3110231435), the only way you can get two licenses on a Battle.net account is if they are from different regions. At that point, you just load the appropriate client and log in with your Battle.net account.