# Is it possible to run more than one Battle.Net game at the same time on different PCs?

Tags: battle.net

I already own Starcraft 2 and, therefore, a Battle.Net account. But I'm not playing it very often, so I let a friend of mine use it.

If I buy Diablo 3 (which I intend to do) and bind it to this very same Battle.Net account, will we be able, my friend an I, to run these two games at the same time on different computers?  Or should I create another Battle.Net account and prey for Blizzard to leave me the hell alone and not asking for an official identification on the rare occasions I connect to the two different Battle.Net accounts with the same IP?

Comment: I was logged in the Diablo III Beta and World of Warcraft at the same time. I don't know if it acted differently because D3 was in Beta or not. Battle.Net just showed me as online with D3 because that is what I logged into first.

Comment: However be aware that account sharing is a bannable offense. If it is found out, Blizzard can ban your account with no questions asked. It would probably be safer to tell your friend to get their own BNet account and play Starcraft on it.

Comment: If you were on the same IP it probably wouldn't be a problem. If you constantly logged in from different IPs with different MAC Addresses they would probably flag the account for further investigation to verify that you haven't been hacked. Blizzard uses Battle.net as DRM for their games. The reason they ban for account sharing is because the people playing the game didn't pay for it. Developers (Indie or Mainstream) need support from it's fans and players if it is going to thrive and survive.

Comment: Even if I have a lot to say about it, let's not troll here.  Thanks for the heads up, I'll keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I buy Diablo 3 (which I intend to do) and bind it to this very same
>   Battle.Net account, will we be able, my friend an I, to run these two
>   games at the same time on different computers?

You can log into Starcraft 2, Diablo III, and all 8 of your World of Warcraft accounts at the sametime if you wanted at.

Of course sharing your account with your friend is a horrible idea, him knowing your password means he can access your account anytime he wants, I suggest logging in for him.

Sharing your account of course is against the Terms of Service.

> Or should I create another Battle.Net account and prey for Blizzard to leave me the hell alone and not asking for an official identification on the rare occasions I connect to the two different Battle.Net accounts with the same IP?

There is no reason to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Account sharing is a violation of the Battle.Net Terms of Use. It could be that this rule is not strictly enforced by Blizzard but I have already heard cases of WoW user accounts banned for this reason.

Therefore I would suggest you to avoid this kind of behavior. Telling your friend to make his own account and buy Starcraft or creating a new account just for Diablo 3 is a your decision.

Comment: Ok, so the technical answer to my question is "yes" -- BUT it goes against the Blizard terms of use.

Comment: This does not answer the question.